# Center text within circle positioning logic

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have the following code that I would like to make a bit more intelligent/mathematical and flexible. I would like to center the text I select within the circle, I would also like to make the circle's radius dependent on how big the text (how many characters the string is) within the circle is. Any suggestions how I could do this?

```
//Add text
UILabel *yourLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(location.x, location.y, 300, 20)];
[yourLabel setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
[yourLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[yourLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName: @"Trebuchet MS" size: 14.0f]];
[yourLabel setText:@"Jack"];
[self.view addSubview:yourLabel];

// create new CAShapeLayer
CAShapeLayer *shapeLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
shapeLayer.path = [[self makeCircleAtLocation:location radius:50.0] CGPath];
shapeLayer.strokeColor = [[UIColor redColor] CGColor];
shapeLayer.fillColor = nil;
shapeLayer.lineWidth = 3.0;
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to draw the text on top of the circle, rather than positioning an UILabel?

Comment: I don't know, would it?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know the size of the text, just use `sizeWithFont:` method in NSString object.

```
NSString *someString = @"some string";
CGSize stringBounds = [someString sizeWithFont:yourLabel.font];
```

Then you can determine how big you should draw the circle.

Comment: Thanks, kind of halfway there though. We can calculate a smaller or larger radius dependent on stringBounds.width but yours + my code still doesn't address the desire to guarantee the text is always centered within the circle, with the same padding on all sides no matter the size of the text.

Answer (score 1):

Lets say you want your label and circle centered at "location" point:

```
//Add text
UILabel *yourLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 20)];
[yourLabel setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
[yourLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[yourLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName: @"Trebuchet MS" size: 14.0f]];
[yourLabel setText:@"Jack"];
yourLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
yourLabel.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight |UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin |  UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin;
yourLabel.center = location;
[self.view addSubview:yourLabel];
```

This should keep your label centered, i didn't test it.

For the size of the circle, you can get the size fo the text with

```
- (CGSize)sizeWithFont:(UIFont *)font
```

for ios6 and for ios7

```
- (CGSize)sizeWithAttributes:(NSDictionary *)attributes
```

and pass in as param the font of the label. For ios7, pass the font like this

```
@{NSFontAttributeName:yourLabel.font}
```

Use the size returned to determine the radius of the circle (I recommend size.width/2 plus some extra padding).

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *objectString = @"Jack Nicholson";
UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName: @"Trebuchet MS" size: 14.0f];
CGSize stringSize = [objectString sizeWithFont:font];

//Add text
UILabel *yourLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(location.x - (stringSize.width/2), location.y - (stringSize.height/2), 300, 20)];
[yourLabel setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
[yourLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[yourLabel setFont:font];
[yourLabel setText:objectString];
[self.view addSubview:yourLabel];

// create new CAShapeLayer
CAShapeLayer *shapeLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
shapeLayer.path = [[self makeCircleAtLocation:location radius:stringSize.width] CGPath];
shapeLayer.strokeColor = [[UIColor redColor] CGColor];
shapeLayer.fillColor = nil;
shapeLayer.lineWidth = 3.0;
```